# sticky alias command

Tags: shell, alias

I want to have the alias `inst` to be used instead of `installpkg /tmp/` and then install packages by `inst <pkg name>`. But in normal alias define, We can not stick alias name to the package name and it gives:

`installpkg /tmp/ <pkg name>` That have space between /tmp/ and

There is a way to use `alias inst="cd /tmp/; installpkg"`; That changes the directory too.

But is there any way to have sticky alias?

Comment: Use a function?

Comment: You are right, I should use function.